# Why changing boolean value inside a class doesn't make effect outside it

Tags: image, android-studio, boolean

I created a class to ensure only two items could be chosen.

All items has a status that can be **True** or **False**.

So the method ask three items and three status. I try to make possible only two items to be visible and with status **True**.

```
class EscolheItens {

    private void escolheItem(boolean um, boolean dois, boolean tres, ImageView one, ImageView two, ImageView three) {
        if (um == false && dois == true && tres == true) {
            one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if ((um == false && dois == true && tres == false) || (um == false && dois == false && tres == true)) {
            one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (um == false && dois == false && tres == false) {
            one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            dois = true; //here I put it true 
            two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I use the method from this class

```
 livrofechado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                livroFechadoStatus = false;
                EscolheItens NovaEscolha = new EscolheItens();
                NovaEscolha.escolheItem(livroFechadoStatus, barrasOuroStatus, antidotoAranhaStatus, livrofechado, barrasOuro, antidotoAranha);
            }
        });

        barrasOuro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                barrasOuroStatus = false;
                EscolheItens NovaEscolha = new EscolheItens();
                NovaEscolha.escolheItem(barrasOuroStatus, antidotoAranhaStatus, livroFechadoStatus, barrasOuro, antidotoAranha, livrofechado);
            }
        });

        antidotoAranha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                antidotoAranhaStatus = false;
                EscolheItens NovaEscolha = new EscolheItens();
                NovaEscolha.escolheItem(antidotoAranhaStatus, livroFechadoStatus, barrasOuroStatus, antidotoAranha, livrofechado, barrasOuro);
            }
        });
```

The problem is **all the boolean keep False**.
I know I set false on all `Onclicks` but inside method they should change.

I really tried many things before posing here. But nothing worked.

Comment: please explain this `um == false && dois && tres`

Comment: dois == true &&   and    tres == true  I've just made the code up clearer

Comment: um, dois, tres are the boolean status for their respective one, two, three ImageView

Comment: you mean `two` should be set to invisible, but it not ?

Comment: I put more information but YES I need some kind of update the informations. i'll check your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the change after the boolean value changed, create a method inside

```
class EscolheItens {
    private void escolheItem(boolean um, boolean dois, boolean tres, ImageView one, ImageView two, ImageView three) {
        if (um == false && dois == true && tres == true) {
            one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if ((um == false && dois == true && tres == false) || (um == false && dois == false && tres == true)) {
            one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (um == false && dois == false && tres == false) {
            one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            dois = true; //here I put it true 
            two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            update(um,dois,tres,one);  // call method
        }
    }

    public void update(boolean um, boolean dois, boolean tres, ImageView one) {
        if (um == false && dois == true && tres == true) {
            one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just show you the idea, you have to implement based on your logic

Comment: private boolean livroFechadoStatus = true;
    private boolean barrasOuroStatus = true;
    private boolean antidotoAranhaStatus = true;

Comment: Man, I found a way to solve it. Once The method isn't updating the boolean I test what image is visible and set this one status as true.

Comment: Your suggestion does the same, it's written to update but in action it doesn't update.

Comment: Congratulation.

Comment: Yep, it's working but I didn't give up. I feel like adding more code than necessary.

Comment: Now I've changed everything, deleted those booleans and start using only decisions by getting the visibility.

Comment: I guess so. Must keep going.